# How to programs tables and columns that are named with spaces?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

There's a database with many tables, reports, and forms that are named with spaces as well as the column names. It wasn't really planned to use VBA when the database was initially created, and now that we try to program in it, we're facing this big challenge on how to query and program without changing the table and column names. It's a VBA Access 2013. Sorry it's not allowing to post a snapshot. Thanks much for your input.

Comment: Enclose in [ ] ie. RS![Some Date]  or 'select ID, [job nbr], flda from  [some table]

Answer (score 1):

You have to just use the square bracket to wrap column name and table name to work with this:- 
Sample code would be

```
    Create table [temp table]
    (
      id int,
      [first name] varchar(50),
      [Last name] varchar(50)
    )


Select id,[first name],[Last name] from 
[temp table]
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36109/1)